# hibernate annotations and joins

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I am trying to use hibernate to retrieve data from my database...I have a query that joins two tables (all fields being one to one) using a left join. I need to know how to handle this with hibernate and annotations. I have created two classes that map to tables and I am trying to figure out how to use the joins...Hibernate docs are confusing...

//one class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Class1")
public class Class1{

 @Id
 @Column(name = "INITIAL")
 private String initial;

  @Column(name = "NUMBER")
  private Integer number;
```

...

//twoclass

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Class2")
public class Class2{

 @Column(name = "STATE")
 private String state;

  @Id   
  @Column(name = "NUMBER")
  private Integer number
```

...

Comment: How are these classes related to each other. What are the tables behind them? It's impossible to design a mapping without knowing the table structures.

Comment: @JBNizet they are two distinct tables however fk for table2 is pk of table 1 note: that there is an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Class1")
public class Class1 {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "INITIAL")
   private String initial;

   @Column(name = "NUMBER")
   private Integer number;  
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "Class2")
public class Class2 {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "STATE")
   private String state;

   @Column(name = "NUMBER")
   private Integer number

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "columnWithClass1id")
   private Class1 class1;
}
```

Comment: How do I tie the two classes together - I call the query in class 1...the query doesnt recognize class 2

Comment: Here you can see all possible solutions, may someone will be helpful